# how to find oldest modified files in SVN

Tags: svn

I'd like to cleanup my code. I would like to do a full SVN search to find files that have been never changed (or changed a very long time ago) and listing everything in DESC order (oldest changed to most recently changed). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is what you really understand about "cleanup" your code ? The best thing is to have unit/integration tests and remove unused parts which not fulfil the intended requirements.

Comment: I want to find files that have not been modified in a long time

Comment: And what's the result out of it? Does that mean you can remove them? I don't think so...

Comment: no it does not, but I will then look at the code and examine to see if it can actually be removed. I want to find the oldest files programmatically but examine them on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The revision of all files/folders shows their latest change, so to retrieve the files just use:

```
svn ls -Rv <URL_TO_REPO/PATH_TO_PROJECT>
```

You will receive a list like this:

```
<REV>   <AUTHOR>  <SIZE>   <DATE>   <filename>
```

You can sort them by unix tool sort, convert them easily to a csv-file and import it to excel or use the --xml switch and make even more complex handling.

Note: You will see only the current files. You will not see any **deleted** files.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest revision number will give you the first hint cause the earlier the files in that changeset have been changed. So you could list them like:

```
svn log URLReposRoot -v
```

in my opinion the best solution is to log out the history as an XML file cause the xml file contains all informations plus all files. After that you can read that XML file and extract the information about need out of it.

```
svn log URLReposRoot -v  --xml >result.xml
```

But this results in a larger script cause that's not that simple in particular if files have been renamed or copied etc.